# Guidelines for developing a document management system

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a task to develop web based DMS. There should exist a database containing users (username and password). Users should log in into the DMS using a web browser. They should be able to upload and download documents (pdfs, word docs, jpegs etc.) and they should be notified when a certain user does that. Also there should be an option to sort those documents by type, date and by the user that uploaded a certain document. Users must be able to give permissions to other users, etc.

I need to use a noSQL db for this project, I was thinking maybe MongoDB in combination with NodeJS? I know how to code html, css, javascript and a bit of php.

I would appreciate if you could give me some advices or links to get me started.

Comment: You __need__ to use a nosql for this? You have no idea about architecture of the thing, but you know you need nosql? How so?

Comment: It is the final project I have to do for the university I'm studying at. My mentor asked me to do it using nosql.

Comment: Ah. In this case, mongodb will do just fine.